# How do to loop many objects in array

Tags: javascript

Hello i have this array

```
const arrayId= [{123, 234, 235}, {345, 456, 564, 560, 653}, {455, 444, 678, 567, 789, 542}]
```

I wan't to loop inside each object in order to apply each item to my endpoint, to be able to retrieve the data of each item

i do that but is don't work

```
 await Promise.all(arrayId.map(async (id) => {
            const contents=await myEndpoint.data(app, id);
            console.log(contents)
          }))
```

Please help me

Comment: Are you looking to do something with each operation, or wait until each operation has completed and _then_ do something?

Comment: I would like to compare the datas of each object to recover the minimum value

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: BTW you can't use `{123, 234, 235}` It's invalid... An object must be a `key-value` pair

Comment: Also, what's `myEndpoint.data()`? Does it return [a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)? You should probably include that code in your question.

Comment: each id returns an object with data when applied to the endpoint

Comment: let's forget the endpoint how to do to loop arrayId is for..in?

Comment: i edit my async function please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `map` is used in these situations to create an array of promises. You can then use `Promise.all` to wait for those promises to resolve/reject. You can then use `Math.min` on the returned data to find the minimum value.

This example uses a dataset that matches yours (mostly), and a fakeFetch call that returns a promise of randomised values based on the ids in each array. It logs the final arrays, and the minimum values of each.

```js
// Accept an array and for each value create a new
// random value. The updated array is sent back as the response
function fakeFetch(arr) {
  const rnd = Math.round(Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1);
  return new Promise(res => {
    const updatedArr = arr.map(el => el * rnd);
    setTimeout(() => res(updatedArr), 2000);
  });
}

// Fetch some data using the array
const myEndpoint = {
  data(arr) { return fakeFetch(arr); }
}

const arr = [[1, 4, 9], [ 2, 10, 4], [ 13, 4, 100 ]];

async function example(arr) {

  // Build an array of promises using the fetch call
  const promises = arr.map(arr => myEndpoint.data(arr));

  // Wait for the response
  const data = await Promise.all(promises);

  // `map` over the arrays to create an array of
  // minimum values
  const mins = data.map(arr => Math.min(...arr));
  console.log(data, mins);
}

example(arr);
```